How to run a python script in dart (for integration testing)
I´m currently writing a integration test for my first flutter application. To automatize the test even more, i want to automatically verify the email via a python script.
In my python script, i log into the specified account via the gmail-API, check if there are any unread emails for verification, and if so - the script clicks on the link in order to verify it.
When I run the script in the command line, it works perfectly fine. The output below shows my comments / that the script works as intended.
C:\...>python C:\...\emailVerification.py
Found verification link: https:\\...
<Response [200]>
Successfully verified email via link

As I wanted to implement the script in my dart file, I did some research and found the "Process" class in dart, which allows running cmd commands in dart.
I came up with this function which is called after the registration of the user (when it is asked to verify the email).
Future<void> runPythonScript() async {
  final result = await Process.start(
    'python',
    ['C:/.../emailVerification.py'],
    environment: {
      'PATH': Platform.environment['PATH']!,
    },
  );

  if (result.exitCode == 0) {
    print("Python script output: ${result.stdout}");
  } else {
    print("Error: ${result.stderr}");
  }
}

However, I get different results than expected. Instead one of the print statements, i get an error from VSC stating that the file could not be found.
Exception has occurred.
ProcessException (ProcessException: No such file or directory
  Command: python C:/.../emailVerification.py)

Altough I have made 100% sure that the file is there and accessible, it can not be found with the code I have written. I have tried some other approaches, but none of them worked properly, so I came here to ask if someone knows a fix - or if it maybe is just not possible with the process package.
Thanks for your help!

I recommend reading the Microsoft documentation about Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces. The directory separator on Windows is \ and not / as on Linux/Mac. The Windows file I/O automatically replaces all / by \ before passing file/folder name or wildcard pattern with an absolute or relative path to the file system, but it is nevertheless syntactically incorrect to use / as directory separator on Windows.

The Dart Process class is not for running cmd commands. It does not start the Windows Command Processor with %ComSpec% /c … as done by the system function in many script interpreters. It calls on Windows the Windows kernel library function CreateProcess with a filled out STARTUPINFO structure.

The Windows Command Processor cmd.exe can be also executed with CreateProcess which is done by the system function used by many script interpreters like on using in Python os.system as being an executable. That makes it possible running internal commands of cmd.exe on calling CreateProcess to run %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe with the options /D and /C and the command line to execute with the internal command(s) of cmd.

But there is a big difference between running an executable directly like with using in Python the subprocess module or the Process class in Dart: CreateProcess does not search for executables or scripts (interpreted by associated and started executable) like cmd.exe using the environment variables PATH and PATHEXT. The usage of the Dart Process class requires therefore fully qualified file names and best also passing the correct directory path for the current working directory to Windows kernel function CreateProcess.

Many Python scripts are not good coded and expect the current working directory is the directory containing the Python script file. That is of course very often a wrong expectation as the process calling CreateProcess for starting python.exe defines the current working directory for Python which can be any directory. I recommend running in a command prompt window where python and use the absolute file name of the found Python executable.

The file not found appears to be python not the script.  Try putting in the absolute path to python to confirm and fix.
Note that the documents recommend using an absolute path for the executable since resolving the executable path is platform-specific.
https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.3.4/dart-io/Process/start.html

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞══ The following ProcessException was thrown running a test: No such file or directory   Command: C:/Python311/python.exe C:/.../emailVerification.py
Thanks for your reply! However, I have already tried this, and sadly it does not work. Although I have provided the full path to the python executable, it still tells me that the file could not be found.

Two things you can try.  Lowercase P for Python311 C:\python311\python.exe and using backslashes instead of forward slashes for the path.  You may have to double backslash them  C:\Python311\python.exe.
